# How to get the class of a div on click of a button?

Tags: jquery

I want to hide the div with the class name "myclass" on the click of a button in that div. Please remember there are more than two div with "myclass" name  with different id d25, d26. And I want to hide only that div whose cancel button is clicked . How can I do this ! Any help will be appreciated. The code I am using is:

```
<div class="myclass" id="d25" >

<form method="post" action="#" >
<input type="email" name="emaild" id="emailid"  />
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="sub"/>
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancel" class="can"  />
</form>

</div>

<div class="myclass" id="d26" >

    <form method="post" action="#" >
    <input type="email" name="emaild" id="emailid"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="sub"/>
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancel" class="can"  />
    </form>

    </div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".can").click(function(){


        //what code I need to put here to hide div myclass on the click of button with class "can"

        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does your title have to do with your question? You want to get the DIV with a specific class, not get the class of a DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : User [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get myClass div in its upper hierarchy.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".can").click(function(){
       $(this).closest('.myclass').hide();
     });
});
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d2Tsg/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).on('click', '.can', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest('.myclass').hide();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$('.can').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('.myclass').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In you function , try this :

$(this).parents('div').fadeOut();

parents('div') -> here you can specify your class name also

Rigin

Answer (score 0):

You can use closest() jquery function e.g.

```
 $('.can').click(function(){

           $(this).closest('.myclass').hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**js**

```
$(".can").click(function(){      
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUTNt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Find the div from the buttons parents using the following and hide it.

```
$(this).parents('div').hide();
```

The code will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".can").click(function(){
       $(this).parents('div').hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6nrc8/`